# SVN: Replacing trunk with a branch

Tags: svn

If you have an SVN branch on which  a huge of amount of work has been done, effectively being the main place for development, is there any special way to decide this branch should become the trunk? A project I'm involved with has this situation, it's kind of like taking a branch of your operating-system code and then replacing the entire kernel.

Is there a 'right' or 'wrong' way to handle this? It seems forcing a branch to merge when it's very different doesn't achieve much, if all the trunk changes have been merged to your branch.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just merge everything back to trunk?

Or if you could (in a single transaction, preferably):

1. Delete the existing trunk.
2. Copy (or rename) the branch to trunk.

Using [svnmucc](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnmucc.re.html) you could do:

```
svnmucc rm http://host/repos/trunk cp HEAD http://host/repos/branches/b http://host/repos/trunk
```

Comment: AS I said, the fear is reintegrating would be a nightmare... I'll test-merge to see but am not optimistic :). Never heard of svnmucc, is it a standard part of SVN or an external tool... I'm running all my SVN through Tortoise on Windows.